# Display `Table` output as a 3D bar chart

Tags: plotting, functions, graphics3d, visualization, charts

Create a simple function with arguments `{i,j}`, and make a `Table` for an array of values. For example:

```
f[i_, j_] := i*j; 
data = Table[f[i, j], {i, 1, 25}, {j, 1, 25}]
```

I want to create a 3D 'bar chart' of `data` - i.e., a plot that has a column of height `f[i, j]` at each Cartesian point `{i,j}` (ideally a block-shaped column with width and depth `1` centred on `{i,j}`. It sounds dead simple...

But `ListPlot3D` creates a meshed surface, not a series of columns, and I can't see an option to change this. And `Histogram3D` doesn't accept the format of `data`, and in any case I can't get my head around how it generates 3D information from pairs containing only 2 data points each - it's set up for data sampling, not plotting.

Suggestions?

Comment: What about `ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, MeshStyle -> None,
 ColorFunction -> Hue]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using some `Cuboid`'s:

```
f[i_, j_] := i*j;
data = Table[f[i, j], {i, 1, 25}, {j, 1, 25}];

bar[{i_, j_}, h_] := 
 Cuboid[{i - 0.5, j - 0.5, 0}, {i + 0.5, j + 0.5, h}]
Graphics3D[{
  MapIndexed[bar[#2, #1] &, data, {2}]
  }, BoxRatios -> 1
 ]
```

[image: cuboid chart]

... and here I've spiced it up with colour, axes, and cylinders:

```
huescale = MinMax[data];
bar[{i_, j_}, h_] := {Hue[Rescale[h, huescale]], 
  Cylinder[{{i, j, 0}, {i, j, h}}, 0.5]}
Graphics3D[{
  MapIndexed[bar[#2, #1] &, data, {2}]
  }, BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {i, j, f}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
]
```

[image: cylinders chart]

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Histogram3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram3D.html) and [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html),

```
wdata =
 WeightedData[
  Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 25}, {j, 25}], 1],
  Apply[f]
  ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then

```
Histogram3D[wdata, {{1}, {1}}]
```

> [image]

See options like [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html), [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html), and other for appearance customization.

Hope this helps.